# Kivy App Quitting When Clicking

Tags: kivy, pyinstaller, python-3.6

I have been trying to turn a kivy app to exe file using pyinstaller, but it keeps giving me errors. I have done exactly what I must do as it states on the [website](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-osx.html#additional-libraries). 
I am using: 
`Mac mini (Late 2014)`
`2.6 GHz Intel Core i5`
`Version 10.12.6`
`python 3.6.1`
`PyInstaller: 3.3`
`Platform: Darwin-16.7.0-x86_64-i386-64bit`
`kivy 1.10.1`

Here is what my main.py looks like:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.6') # replace with your current kivy version !

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello world')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

I have used pyinstaller to run the following command:

```
pyinstaller -y --clean --windowed --name simple \
  --exclude-module _tkinter \
  --exclude-module Tkinter \
  --exclude-module enchant \
  --exclude-module twisted \
  main.py
```

And it keeps giving me this error:
[image: screen shot 2017-11-10 at 2 52 24 pm]

I have tried to ignore it, and just keep doing what is said on the [website](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-osx.html#additional-libraries). That is, adding the tree object:

```
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               Tree('/Users/mohammadmohjoub/PycharmProjects/Kivy'), 
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='simple')
```

and running the following command: 
`pyinstaller -y --clean --windowed simple.spec`

Now it made it worst because I got the same error that I had above, and this new error: 
`WARNING: stderr: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/mohammadmohjoub/PycharmProjects/Kivy/dist/simple.app/Contents/Resources/lib2to3/Grammar.txt'`

[image: screen shot 2017-11-10 at 3 02 14 pm]

What is the reason for `ModuleNotFoundError` error, and the `FileNotFoundError` error? Is this is why every time I try to open the app it just closes immediately? If that is not the reason, then how can I build the app in a way that doesn't make it close unexpectedly? I have been trying to fix this for weeks. I would really appreciate any kind of support.

Answer (score 0):

1) For the first error (module not found). I am confused as to why you are using the `--exclude-module` flag. If your project depends on those modules, they need to be packaged together with your script. In fact, you may even need to use the `--hidden-import` flag to identify those modules which pyinstaller may not find.

https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html

This link gives you information about the `--hidden-import` flag. But this may not be necessary if all the paths are set properly. But as an example:

```
pyinstaller -y --clean --windowed --hidden-import=module_name simple.py
```

**Note**
You may need to provide the full path to the modules of your hidden-import. You can add that with the `--paths="path\to\your\module"` flag. This will tell pyinstaller where to look for things. You can also just add the full file path to the `--hidden-import` flag. Either way you need to specify the full path somewhere (you can edit the pathex variable in the spec file as well).

2) For the second error (File not found). If your code accesses external files (such as Grammar.txt). It needs to be bundled with pyinstaller as well. When pyinstaller compiles your code, it creates a "dist" directory where you run your code from, but your python script (i assume) is looking for this file based on the relative location to the original script. So you need to either copy over the file to your directory, or use the `--add-data` flag when compiling. The above link gives information on that flag as well.

```
pyinstaller -y --clean --windowed --add-data="src:dest" simple.py
```

---

Another solution is to just edit the spec file to include everything:

```
a = Analysis(['minimal.py'],
    ...
    datas=[('src/Grammar.txt', '.'), ('another/src/more.txt', '.')]
    hiddenimports=['path_to_import', 'path_to_second_import'],
    ...
    cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
    cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,... )
coll = COLLECT(...)
app = BUNDLE(...)
```

Then you can just do: `pyinstaller your.spec`

For more information on spec files: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html

Comment: I have tried all the things that you suggested and sadly nothing works. The errors keep appearing, and app keeps turning off as soon as I click it.

Comment: @MohammadMahjoub which of the errors keeps appearing?

Comment: can you post the spec file you are using? also are there any warnings when you compile?

Comment: Since I am getting both `enchant - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'enchant'` and `osxappkit - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'AppKit'` errors when running: `pyinstaller -y --clean --windowed --name simple \
  --exclude-module _tkinter \
  --exclude-module Tkinter \
  --exclude-module enchant \
  --exclude-module twisted \
  simple.py`  , so I ran this instead: `pyinstaller -y --clean --windowed --hidden-import=enchant --hidden-import=AppKit simple.py` But it still keeps giving me the same error. That is, `No module named 'enchant'` and `No module named 'AppKit'`

Comment: Are there any warnings when you compile? are enchant and AppKit in your path?

Comment: Yes, when I run: `pyinstaller -y --clean --windowed --hidden-import=enchant --hidden-import=AppKit simple.py` I get: `No module named 'enchant'` and `No module named 'AppKit'`exceptions. And if "in your path" mean in your directory, then no. How can I make them in my path?

Comment: you may need to provide a direct file path to where the module is located

Comment: If I know where the files are located, then how can I provide the path?

Comment: Thank you God, and @The4thIceman. I was able to get it running using `--onefile` command but the terminal window appears when application  is running. Is there is a way to prevent the terminal window from appearing?

Comment: normally you would use the --noconsole flag. But from documentation: "This option is ignored in *NIX systems", which would be Macs